# In Paper.js, when .subtract divides the shape into multiple regions, is it possible to separate them?

Tags: paperjs, boolean-operations

Here is an example adapted from http://paperjs.org/examples/boolean-operations/ :
[http://sketch.paperjs.org](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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)

Since the rectangle cuts all the way through the square, the `square.subtract(pole)` operation results in a single path containing two closed regions. Is there a way in Paper.js to separate them into 2 paths I can change independently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `.subtract` actually is a CompoundPath. It doesn't appear to be in the example above because setting fill color on one of the children of a compound path doesn't work; the style of a CompoundPath is shared by all children.

The subpaths can be accessed via `.children` and changed independently when they are taken out of the compound path. See [example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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).